# User Opt-in from Website form & Automated Welcome message (Whatsapp + SMS)

Tags: sms, whatsapp, gupshup

Is following flow possible in GupShup? (for User Opt-in & sending automated Welcome message for both **Whatsapp** & **SMS**)

1. I keep a textbox & Button on my site
2. User will enter mobile number & clicks the button
3. User's number get added to my opt-in users list
4. User will receive automated welcome message on their whatsapp from my whatsapp account
5. User will receive automated welcome SMS message on their mobile

Answer (score 0):

i think you can do this with api provided by gupshup https://api.gupshup.io/sm/api/v1/msg

you have to write channel=whatsapp